# Infinite graphs with large degree but no perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

Is there an example of an infinite connected, simple, undirected graph $G = (V,E)$ such that every vertex has $|V|$ neighbors, but $G$ does not have a perfect matching (that is, a set $M\subseteq E$ of pairwise disjoint edges such that $\bigcup M = V$)?

Comment: What’s a perfect matching?

Comment: A set $M$ of pairwise disjoint edges such that $\bigcup M = V$

Comment: @BenBarber oh indeed, and it is answered by our student, and I remember now that I have seen this post :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the ordering on $V$ such that for any vertex $v$ there exist less than $|V|$ vertices $y<x$. Construct the matching inductively.